# PHP image upload compression not working. Can you take a look at my code?

Tags: php, image, upload, resize, compression

You guys are my last resort. I've been at this problem for over a day now and still can't find the solution. My code I listed below works fine. It uploads the renamed image to the correct directory. The only thing that doesn't work is that it doesn't compress the image. The file size for the new image is the exact size as the original image.

I was wondering if you can take a look at my code below and see if you can spot something I am not doing right?

I have an image compression code that I borrowed from examples I saw on this site and other sites. This is it.

```html
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {

  $info = getimagesize($source_url);

  if($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg' || $info['mime'] == 'image/jpg') {

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);

  } else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {

    $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);

  } else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {

    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

  } else {
    $image = null;
  }

  imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
  return $destination_url;
}
```

And here is my image upload script.

```html
if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']) AND !empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']["name"])) {
  if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']["tmp_name"])) {

    $target_dir    = '../members/images/'.$global_user_id.'/projects/'.$url_project_id.'/';
    $target_file   = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $source_file   = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    $random_name   = generateRandomString(10);
    $new_image     = $random_name . '.' . $imageFileType;
    $resized_image = compress_image($source_file, $new_image, 75);
    $new_file_path = $target_dir . $resized_image;

    if(!is_dir($target_dir)){
      mkdir($target_dir, 0775, true);
    }

    $uploadOk      = 1;
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($source_file);
    if($check !== false) {
     //   echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'File is not an image!';
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, file already exists!';
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, your file size is bigger than 5mb!';
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "PNG" && $imageFileType != "JPEG" && $imageFileType != "GIF") {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed!';
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if($uploadOk == 0) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, your file was not uploaded!';
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {

      if(move_uploaded_file($source_file, $new_file_path)) {

        echo 'success';

      } else {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, there was an error uploading your file!';
      }
    }
  } else {
    $errors[] = 'You must upload an image!';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($source_file, $new_file_path)) {
```

You're moving the original file. You should move `$new_image`:

```
if(rename($new_image, $new_file_path)) {
```

Comment: So like this? if(move_uploaded_file($new_image, $new_file_path)) { --- if I do this, it won't upload the image and would give me the error associated with it "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file!".

Comment: @johnsmith Yes, `$new_image` is not an updated file. Updated answer

Comment: So I replaced move_uploaded_file with "rename" as per your example. It now uploads the image. But now the new image is almost twice the file size as the original.

Comment: @johnsmith Use a smaller `$quality`. Try 10

Comment: Oh wow. It works now. The file size is smaller. May I ask why use "rename" as oppose to "move_uploaded_file" and why lower number like 10 lowered the size file 75 increased it?

Comment: @johnsmith `move_uploaded_file` is the same as `rename` except that it fails if the file isn't one that was uploaded. `$new_image` was created by the server. A low `$quality` keeps less data about the file. That's why it looks worse.

Comment: Good to know that. Thank you so much for your help!